# Get percent value of animation

Tags: jquery, css, animation, cubic-bezier

Let's say I have following:

**CSS**

```
.animatedItem {
    background-color: red;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    transition: all 1200ms cubic-bezier(0.39, 0.575, 0.565, 1);
}
.animatedItemSate1 {
    margin-left: 0px;
}
.animatedItemState2 {
    margin-left: 200px;
}
```

**JQuery**

```
$('.animatedItem.animatedItemSate1')
     .removeClass('animatedItemSate1')
     .addClass('animatedItemState2');

// get X percent of animation
var percent = 30; // 30% of animation
var animationValue = '?'; // animation value at 30%
alert(animationValue);
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="animatedItem animatedItemSate1"><div>
```

```js
$('.animatedItem.animatedItemSate1')
  .removeClass('animatedItemSate1')
  .addClass('animatedItemState2');

// get X percent of animation
var percent = 30; // 30% of animation
var animationValue = '?'; // animation value at 30%
console.log(animationValue);
```

```css
.animatedItem {
  background-color: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  transition: all 1200ms cubic-bezier(0.39, 0.575, 0.565, 1);
}

.animatedItemSate1 {
  margin-left: 0px;
}

.animatedItemState2 {
  margin-left: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="animatedItem animatedItemSate1">
  <div>
```

It runs not linear css3 animation. I need to get animation value of 30%(or any other) before animation runs. How to get that?
I've created a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/syom777/xnpfzyoL/8/

> Update:
>   There is similar discussion here: [CSS3 animation "progress" callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31910916/css3-animation-progress-callback)

I think we can apply another way to get it, because in cubic-bezier(0.39, 0.575, 0.565, 1) line we have the algorithm of animation, so there should be a way to get any value from there.

Thanks.

Comment: Hello kindly check my old post [CSS3 Animation Progress Callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31910916/css3-animation-progress-callback).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS3 animation "progress" callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31910916/css3-animation-progress-callback)

Comment: Hi, I've just checked it. I think that there should be some way to get it, because in cubic-bezier(0.39, 0.575, 0.565, 1) line we have the algorithm of animation, so there should be a way to get any value from there.

Comment: https://github.com/gre/bezier-easing